# Making mysql query to tables based on the values from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query and it is working fine. If you see the query you would notice that there is a variable called `$code`, and I use to manually set its value like this `$code="1001";`

```
function check1() { 

$code="1001";

 $getData = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM vouchers 
 LEFT JOIN  details on vouchers.voucher_no = details.voucher_no 
LEFT JOIN   accounts on accounts.code = vouchers.account_code 
WHERE (voucher_type='1' AND t_code=$code)

 UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM vouchers 
LEFT JOIN details on vouchers.voucher_no = details.voucher_no 
LEFT JOIN   accounts on accounts.code = details.t_code 
 WHERE (voucher_type='0' AND account_code=$code)

 ");

       if($getData->num_rows() > 0)
        return $getData->result_array();
        else
        return null;
}
```

And when I display the result in my view file, I use the following script:

```
  <?php if(count($records) > 0) { ?>

  <?php $i = $this->uri->segment(3) + 0; foreach ($records as $row){ $i++; ?>

  <?php echo $row['voucher_date']; ?>  
  <?php echo $row['name']; ?> 
  <?php echo $row['amount']; ?>    <br>

<?php  } ?>

<?php } else { echo "No Record Found";} ?>

<?php 
$sum = 0;
foreach ( $records as $row ) {
 $sum += str_replace(",", "", $row['amount']);
}
?> 

  Total: <?php  echo  number_format( $sum, 2 );?>
```

Now what I want to do is get the value of `$code` from the following mysql table and get the result for all its values, so that when I display the results in my view file it doesn't show results for `$code="1001"`only but also for `$code="1002"` , `$code="1003"` .

To achieve what I want to get, I have to change the mysql query above.But I don't understand how to do it, would you please kindly show me.

Thanks in Advance:)

Table Name: accounts

```
code   name 
1001    Cash Account
1002    Advertising Expense
1003    Accounts Receivable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM vouchers 
 LEFT JOIN  details on vouchers.voucher_no = details.voucher_no 
LEFT JOIN   accounts on accounts.code = vouchers.account_code 
WHERE voucher_type='1' AND t_code IN (SELECT * FROM code_table)

 UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM vouchers 
LEFT JOIN details on vouchers.voucher_no = details.voucher_no 
LEFT JOIN   accounts on accounts.code = details.t_code 
 WHERE voucher_type='0' AND account_code IN (SELECT * FROM code_table)
```